# Python: String to list (without changing a word)

Tags: python, string, list

** If you try to run code, please set Tall as string, thanks.

I scraped this from the website from POST, Tall looks like a list but it is not. It is a "string", I already used some split to make it neat. I just want to know if there a way to make it as a list and use simple way to extract data. Otherwise it'll be difficult for me to split all of them.

Type of Tall is string and I want to extract values from Tall:

```
Tall=[{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"2002","CERTPHOTO1":"Y"},
 {"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"4791","CERTPHOTO1":""}]
```

Code:

```
print(type(Tall))
```

class 'str'

```
print(Tall[1])
```

{

But when I tried to do this:

```
for i in range(2):
    result=list(Tall[i].values())
```

The error says:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I want to make Tall from string to a list without changing anything of Tall, is it possible?

The result I expected:

```
2018/02/06,2002,Y
2018/02/06,4791,
```

Comment: Type of Tall looks like a `list`.

Comment: @Bijoy I know, but it's not. I already did some split to make it look neat, so it will be easier to extract the value. I scraped them from the website.

Comment: This code runs without error.

Comment: If you want help you must provide a [mcve], that is, a code that reproduces your error, I have executed your code and I do not get any error.

Comment: @StephenRauch I know what you mean, but Tall is a string, not list. So you need to set is as a string first to do it

Comment: @eyllanesc I scraped them from websites, how do I provide 100000 datas? You need to set Tall as a string first to run it.

Comment: If tall needs to be *set* as a string, then *set* in your question.

Comment: I do not see that you have placed a string, you must provide a [mcve], nobody asked for all the data, if you had read the link I would understand that it is a [mcve], **Minimal**, for example: `some_var = """Tall=[{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"2002","CERTPHOTO1":"Y"},
 {"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"4791","CERTPHOTO1":""}]"""`

Comment: is `Tall="""[{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"2002","CERTPHOTO1":"Y"},
 {"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"4791","CERTPHOTO1":""}]"""` or `some_var = """Tall=[{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"2002","CERTPHOTO1":"Y"},
 {"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"4791","CERTPHOTO1":""}]"""`????

Comment: Read what a [mcve] means, also review [ask]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. In your code, Tall is syntactically defined as a list containing two dictionaries, not a string.

Comment: Use `json` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your TALL is str like this. (Added single quotes to be string). The answer to your question (how to convert string to list) is via *eval*.

```
>>> tall_str = '[{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"2002","CERTPHOTO1":"Y"},{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"4791","CERTPHOTO1":""}]'
>>> print(type(tall_str))
<class 'str'>
```

(1) json.loads

```
>>> import json
>>> tall_list = json.loads(tall_str)
>>> print(type(tall_list))
<class 'list'>
```

(2) eval

```
>>> tall_list = eval(tall_str)
>>> print(type(tall_list))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: `eval()` may be overkill and unsafe.

Comment: Maybe using `json.loads()` instead of `eval()` is a good idea

Comment: @bla Good suggestion. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `json.loads()` for that:

```
>>> import json
>>> tall = json.loads('[{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06", "CARID":"2002","CERTPHOTO1":"Y"},{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"4791","CERTPHOTO1":""}]')
>>> tall
[{'SALEDATE': '2018/02/06', 'CARID': '2002', 'CERTPHOTO1': 'Y'}, {'SALEDATE': '2018/02/06', 'CARID': '4791', 'CERTPHOTO1': ''}]
>>> tall[0]
{'SALEDATE': '2018/02/06', 'CARID': '2002', 'CERTPHOTO1': 'Y'}
>>> tall[0].values()
dict_values(['2018/02/06', '2002', 'Y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `__getitem__` special method is one simplest way to achieve your desired result.

Here's how I have solved your problem:

```
Tall=[{"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"2002","CERTPHOTO1":"Y"}, {"SALEDATE":"2018/02/06","CARID":"4791","CERTPHOTO1":""}]
for i in Tall:
    sale = i.__getitem__('SALEDATE')
    carid = i.__getitem__('CARID')
    photo = i.__getitem__('CERTPHOTO1')
    print(sale,',',carid,',',photo)
```

On executing the above code, we'll land up in the exact result you had asked for:

```
2018/02/06, 2002, Y
2018/02/06, 4791,
```